setInterval method getting wrong lastChild and i don't know why?


const randomDelay = ()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const timeout = (Math.random()*10)%7;
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, timeout*1000);
    });
}
const addItem = async(item)=>{
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = item;
    document.body.append(div);
        //console.log("append=",div);
    await randomDelay();
    div.innerHTML = item + "..!";
}

async function main() {
    let t = setInterval(() => {
        let last = document.body.lastChild;
        //console.log("last=",last.innerHTML);
        if(last.innerHTML.endsWith("...")){
            last.innerHTML = last.innerHTML.slice(0,last.innerHTML.length -3);
        }
        else{
            last.innerHTML += ".";
        }
    }, 300);
    let items = ["Initializing Hacking",
    "Reading your files",
    "Password Files Detected",
    "Sending all passwords and personal files to server",
    "Cleaning up"];
//If I uncomment the below line then it working after a randomDelay();
    // await randomDelay();
    for (const item of items) {
        await addItem(item);
    }
    await randomDelay();
    clearInterval(t);

}
console.log("look down here")
main();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>top</body>
</html>



The above is script.js code and in html file there is only boiler plate code.
I am trying to put a "three dots while loading" effect using a random delay but it is not working for the first line. Also, when the line is done it is set to end with three three dots (inside addItem; NOTE: edited to ..! for clarity) but that is not working for the last element of the array.
If anyone can please explain the flow of execution it will be a great help!!!

In your randomDelay() function, timeout should be declared: const timeout = ...

Also t in main(). Always declare your variables with let or const. Ideally, work in strict mode so you'll get an error when you forget.

@Pointy i have correct the mistake you suggested but still it is not working.

In order for the code in the setinterval to execute there can’t be any other code currently running in the main thread.  Awaiting an async function like randomdelay gives an opportunity for the setinterval to also run.

@James ok i understand but can i do anything to continuous execute the setInterval() method?
